# Get matching and non matching records using Regex and LINQ

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have a list of string with with 20 items like below

```
List<string> votingcodes = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"};
```

I am using regex pattern to get the matching data in dataview from another datatable like below

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
     var r = new Regex("^.*\\b" + votingcodes[i] + "\\b.*$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

     DataView dv = (from t in dtFetch.AsEnumerable()
                    where r.IsMatch(t.Field<string>("FMSG_IN").ToUpper())
                    select t).AsDataView();
}
```

After getting the data I update the records but I need non matching data as well from dtFetch datatable.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: `where !r.IsMatch(t.Field<string>("FMSG_IN").ToUpper())` ?

Comment: I know ! is applicable but that would make two loops , one for matching and another for non matching.Also , it will give me non matching data from 2-20 on first loop which is not correct.

Comment: You should mention that in your question. However, do you really need a `DataView` as result? Because you can't add another column which is needed to indicate whether it is a matching row or not.

Comment: I was using dataview to get count of matching data which also contains columns used for updating records as per ID. 
If you suggest then we can update records 1 by 1 using dtFetch DataTable where if matching returns true else false and I do the update accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get both results in one query you could use `GroupBy` or `ToLookup`. I think you don't need the loop at all:

```
List<string> votingcodes = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"};
var matchRegexes = votingcodes
    .Select(c => new Regex("^.*\\b" + c + "\\b.*$", RegexOptions.Compiled));
var matchLookup = dtFetch.AsEnumerable()
    .ToLookup(row => matchRegexes
        .Any(r => r.IsMatch(row.Field<string>("FMSG_IN").ToUpper())));
var matchRows = matchLookup[true];
var noMatchRows = matchLookup[false];
DataView dvMatch = null;
DataView dvNoMatch = null;
if (matchRows.Any())
    dvMatch = matchRows.CopyToDataTable().DefaultView;
if (noMatchRows.Any())
    dvNoMatch = noMatchRows.CopyToDataTable().DefaultView;
```

Comment: This would again give me incorrect data on first loop when the value of i =1 then dvMatch will return all records with 1 in string but dvNoMatch will return remaining data from loop 2-20 as incorrect which is technically correct.

Comment: Tell me one more thing , currently I am taking 1 item from the list in regex pattern and then getting the records. Is there any way to get rid of loop and get the pattern of all 20 items in var and then your code could work for me

Comment: @Mohsin: show some sample values in `FMSG_IN` column. Are you sure you need regex?

Comment: Values will be voting numbers which are in the list . Some example are
1,
2 My Signature,
I vote for 3,
My favorite is 4

Comment: @Mohsin: so basically you are searching for an integer? What if there are two, f.e. `1 want 0`?

Comment: If voting code[1-20] is found in the string then I update the record.
But the problem is voting code[1-20] can be anywhere in the string and that string might contain their phone number as signature like 123456789 which is incorrect for me. So only string containing [1-20] should be passed.

Comment: Oh man, this is exactly what I wanted. I wanted the complete list as 1 pattern instead of looping it 1 by 1. Thank you , Thank you very much.